# Как достать фотографию на аватарке группы/чата/канала в Телеграмм?

Tags: php, yii2, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте, необходимо достать фотографию группы/чата/канала которая стоит на аватарке группы,возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Если ответ отвечает на заданные вопросы, то отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 0):

Для получения юзерпика предоставляется метод [getUserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos), однако он работает только для пользователей - для групп и каналов доступных средств получения аватарки нет.